# How to mix music in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, windows-11

In Windows 11 Home I play music with VLC and I would like to mix the tracks like DJs mix tracks in parties.

I went to Effects and filters > Adjustments and Effects > Synchronization but I don't know what to do from there or if it even the right place.

How to do that?

Comment: This question probably belongs in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You'd be far better off using an app specific to the task.

Comment: You need a software like this one [VirtualDJ](https://www.virtualdj.com/)